# Retrofit identify response uniquely

Tags: android, retrofit

I am making multiple request to same web service with different parameters (42 times).

The response that I get doesnt have any parameter by which I can identify the response wrt to request. Is there any parameter I can sent in request that I can get in callback? Like an int id.

Here is my code:

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(Urls.METHOD_NUMBER_STATUS)
    void numberStatus(@FieldMap Map<String, String> map, Callback<NumberStatusResponse> cb);
```

Webservice calling code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.size(); i ++) {

        phone = phoneNumbers.get(i).getNumber();

        builder.build().create(RetroClient.class).numberStatus(Webservices.numberStatus(username, password, phone, token, version), this);
    }
```

Here is my callback in the activity:

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: @ShreenivasChikati please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `phone` as a parameter and checked it in the response.

```
public void onResponse(NumberStatusResponse response) {
    for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.size(); i ++) {
        if (phoneNumbers[i].getNumber() == response.phone) {
            phoneNumbers[i].setStatus(response.status);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```